# write into a tun interface and forward traffic to another computer

Tags: iptables, routing, tun

I have the following setup. An application on machine `A` creates an `IP` packet which is captured by the `tun1` interface. I have added the route using the command :

`sudo route add -host 10.129.131.220 tun1`.

[image]

Then I read the packets from the `tun1` file-descriptor and write to another `UDP` client socket with destination address `B`. I can read packets on the `B` machine. I verified with `tshark` on machine `B` where `tshark` shows following types of outputs.

`1 0.000000000 10.129.131.170 → 10.129.131.220 UDP 51 34611 → 8080 Len=23` and more similar rows.

Now I want to route these `IP` packets to machine C, (actual destination machine). I have created a `tun1` interface in machine `B` and writing the received packets on machine `B`. Writes are successful and `watch -n 1 "ifconfig tun1"` shows the `RX packets` values getting incremented.

I have enables the packet forwarding in machine `B` by setting

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

My question is, how to properly add forwarding rule in machine `B` so that `IP packets` are routed to machine `C` without the addition of more `IP` header. I think writing to a `tun1` device (on B) again might do the work. But how to route from `tun1` to `eth0`?

Update :

One way forwarding is working with the `rp_filter` turned off.
[image]

Now how to route the downlink packets from machine `C` to `A` via `B`?

Thanks!

Comment: it worked with the following filter on the `B` machine

`sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.tun1.rp_filter=0`

`sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0`